# FFmpeg video creation getting stuck while executed from java

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am using this line of code to create a simple video from an image.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i C:\mydir\img.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p test2.mp4
```

it works flawlessly if I execute it from the cmd. But if I call it from my java program I begin to see some lines of ffmpeg but it gets stuck on this line

```
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 110x162 [SAR 1:1 DAR 55:81], 0.20 tbr, 0.20 tbn, 0.20 tbc
```

note that eclipse doesn't say that the program is < terminated >. 
This is the method I'm using to call the command:

```
try{
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "cmd.exe", "/c",
                    //"cd \"C:\\Users\\Davide\\Downloads\\ffmpeg-20160811-b83d907-win64-static\\bin\" && "
                    ffCommand);

    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
```

where `ffcommand` is the line of code I wrote first.
Thanks.

Comment: Rather than passing the full command line arg as a single string, try passing each as its own argument to ProcessBuilder eg `new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-framerate", "1/5", "-i", "C:\mydir\img.jpg"...)`

Comment: Since it's a single image, you can skip the framerate option.

Comment: you said many alarming things already "eclipse" "ffcommand is the line of code I wrote first"...  no need to go on further

Comment: I'll try separating the commands. Weird thing is that a while ago I tested it and it worked. @Mulvya I need it to set the lenght and @ gpasch I don't understand

Comment: You set length via `-loop 1 -t D`. Skip the framerate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it still works from cmd but not from java.